# leaflet not working with shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I was trying to construct a simple app using Shiny and Leaflets to plot some locations.

First I've tried locally the Leaflet plot and it worked, but when using it with Shiny I've got the following error

```
ERROR: argument is not interpretable as logical
```

I've thought I've done something wrong so I went back to the basics and try to run the example app in the [Leaflet website](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html) with the same result. I've tried to run it as a single file (app.R) using the runApp() command and also tried separating the server.R and ui.R with the same result.

I've re-installed leaflet, shiny and still the same.

Any idea of what might be going on?

Full error message:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6991
Warning: Error in if: argument is not interpretable as logical
Stack trace (innermost first):
    54: sprintf
    53: tag
    52: tags$div
    51: widget_html
    50: htmltools::tagList
    49: htmlwidgets::shinyWidgetOutput
    48: leafletOutput
    47: tag
    46: tags$div
    45: div
    44: tagList
    43: attachDependencies
    42: bootstrapPage
    41: fluidPage
    40: shinyUI
     1: shiny::runApp
Error in if (inline) "display: inline-block;" else "" : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
```

R version details

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.2                         
year           2015                        
month          08                          
day            14                          
svn rev        69053                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
nickname       Fire Safety
```

And this is the session info:

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] leaflet_1.0.0 shiny_0.13.1 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.3      digest_0.6.9     mime_0.4         plyr_1.8.3       R6_2.1.2        
 [6] xtable_1.8-2     jsonlite_0.9.19  magrittr_1.5     scales_0.3.0     tools_3.2.2     
[11] htmlwidgets_0.6  munsell_0.4.3    httpuv_1.3.3     yaml_2.1.13      colorspace_1.2-6
[16] htmltools_0.3
```

Comment: can you post an example of the code and data you're using that generates the error?

Comment: also, what version of R? The example leaflet app you've linked to works fine for me

Comment: Hi tospig, thanks for replying. The code is exactly the same as the example leaflet app. My R version is "fire safety" 3.2.2, I've updated the post with the details

Comment: you should also include your sessionInfo()

Comment: Thanks, updated now with seassionInfo

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to make it work when I updated to the latest version of R, the 3.2.3

Comment: odd that it didn't work in the previous version, though.

Comment: Indeed, Apparently the latests version of Leaflet was developed under R 3.2.3, but I cannot think on something working on this new version but not on the previous one... Anyway, thank you very much for your help, the guidelines about sharing the R version and session info gave me the idea of updating R :)